# How to stop teams tab to redirecting to webpage

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am working on teams tab, looking for a solution to stop teams tab redirecting to browser or redirecting to any website from **website icon** on top right corner.

Comment: Currently You cannot stop the tab redirecting to browser from the website icon on the top right corner. This is By design.

Comment: Is there any way to change the URL, where icon is redirecting to?

Comment: No, You cannot change the URL. This is by design.

Comment: is this for a static ( aka personal) tab or for a configurable tab ( channel / chat)

Comment: @JosVerlinde we are working on configurableTab and pointing configurationUrl to our Angular website.

Answer (score 1):

For a **configurable tab** , in your config page you call [`setSettings()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/create-tab-pages/configuration-page#configuring-a-channel-or-group-chat-tab).

There you specify:

- the entityId,
- **contentUrl**,
- the **websiteUrl**,
- and optionally the removeUrl

Here you can leave the `websiteUrl` empty/null/None

Note that you will need to provide a content `contentUrl` which will point to your angular app/site to render the tab in Teams.

However it is important to be aware that this may have impact on the way a mobile client renders the tab.

- If you distribute your App via the **tenant store** , this will have no impact.
- For a published store app (via Appsource), the app needs to be approved / whitelisted to use the url in `contentUrl`. (this should be handled by the AppValidation Team)

  - Apps that are approved for mobile will use the `contentUrl`
  - Non-approved apps will use the `websiteUrl`, and if you did not provide that , there is nothing to display.

This process is intended make sure existing Apps+Tabs properly render on mobile devices,
and is something to be aware of when design / deploying and sending the app for store approval.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/what-are-tabs#mobile-clients

also see :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teamstabconfiguration?view=graph-rest-1.0